# Magento 2: What Determines if a Request is "Full Page Cacheable"

Tags: php, magento2, cache, full-page-cache

Magento 2 comes stock with a full page caching feature.  However, it's not clear how the framework determines which URL end-points need to be cached. For example, if I create a simple controller that acts as a JSON endpoint

```
$data = ...;
$result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();       
return $result->setData($data);
```

The system seems smart enough to **know** not to cache this.

```
curl -I 'http://magento2.example.com/my/custom/endpoint'
//...
X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS
```

I've been able to track the built in caching functionality to this method (used by the built-in plugin)

```
#File: lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php
public function process(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response)
{
    if (preg_match('/public.*s-maxage=(\d+)/', $response->getHeader('Cache-Control')->getFieldValue(), $matches)) {
        $maxAge = $matches[1];
        $response->setNoCacheHeaders();
        if ($response->getHttpResponseCode() == 200 && ($this->request->isGet() || $this->request->isHead())) {
            $tagsHeader = $response->getHeader('X-Magento-Tags');
            $tags = $tagsHeader ? explode(',', $tagsHeader->getFieldValue()) : [];

            $response->clearHeader('Set-Cookie');
            $response->clearHeader('X-Magento-Tags');
            if (!headers_sent()) {
                header_remove('Set-Cookie');
            }
            $this->cache->save(serialize($response), $this->identifier->getValue(), $tags, $maxAge);
        }
    }
}
```

Which seems to examine the response object, and only cache requests if they're a `HTTP 200`, either a `GET` or `HEAD` request.  It also uses the Max-Age `Cache-Control` header to ensure values are saved in the cache for an appropriate amount of time.

So, it's clear from this code that **something** instructs the system (i.e. sets cache headers on the response) to cache the request.  What's not clear is where this happens during Magento's request flow, and which requests gets full page caching and which do not.

Comment: For me, `X-Magento-Cache-Debug` is always `MISS`. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: So how can I cache my Json response? Is this not possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Response is marked as cacheable in `\Magento\PageCache\Model\Layout\LayoutPlugin::afterGenerateXml` only in case if there are no blocks in the layout of current page marked with `cacheable="false"` attribute, like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Registration" name="checkout.registration" template="registration.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

By default all CMS, product and category pages should be cacheable, their layouts were refactored so as not to contain non-cacheable blocks.

Also keep in mind, there is a bug related to usage of `cacheable="false"` on product pages described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86674/block-with-cachable-false-not-rendered-on-product-view-page/90130#90130).

Comment: Thanks!  More on some other important full page cache points here. http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/134802803800/magento-2-full-page-caching-code-points

Comment: But what about when if i need in custom product extended block ? because if i am put `cacheable="false"` in xml then it will give error in varnish `varnish failed` on marketplace submission

Comment: I read your article @AlanStorm. So what is the solution to cache my Json responses?