# How to disable caching of custom block on product view page?

Tags: product, magento2, cache, full-page-cache

I have customBlock in `product_view`. How do  disable cache for this?

Answer (score 10):

I assume you want to disable caching of the block by `PageCache` module. There are two options available:

1. Set `cacheable="false"` attribute in layout. But this will make the whole product page non-cacheable, probably is not what you want. Keep in mind [existing issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90130/697) with `cacheable="false"` on product view page
2. Use [UI components](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html)
3. Do not set `_isScopePrivate` property to `true` in your block, this is deprecated functionality

Comment: Thank alot . i will try it and answer you soon

Comment: @xanka Did it help?

Comment: @Alex Paliarush I tried to set _isScopePrivate to true in my custom block to add a specific logo for the customer of tier price; but it seems not work. My custom block was not rendered by ajax.

Comment: cacheable="false" disables caching for the whole page! This is a recipe for performance degradation. See https://inviqa.com/blog/how-full-page-cache-works-magento-2 for details about caching.

Comment: @Rick.C "Do not use the $_isScopePrivate property in your blocks. This property is obsolete and won't work properly."  Find this in magento guide: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html. I think this links is also helpful to guide how to disable cache in certain blocks.

Comment: @xanka Do you find solution for it? I want to get customer detail in my custom widget. And I don't want to use **cacheable="false"**, as it will disable cache for the pages. Please let me know if you found any solution.

Comment: Find any solution Guys ?

Comment: set _isScopePrivate property to true in your block it will work.

Comment: _isScopePrivate doesn't work