# Magento 2 - Page content is not refresh if cache is enabled

Tags: magento2, cache

I have developed a custom module the retrieve data from database and displayed in a block. The data is updated in database but the page is not showing the latest data if cached is enabled. If the cache is disabled, everything just works fine. Sometimes, even cannot get the customer ID from session if cache is enabled. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: This should help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103256/how-to-disable-the-cache-for-the-block-in-magento-2?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out that if we need to get current customer session in a block, `cacheable` must be set to `false` in the layout xml.

Answer (score 1):

Cacheable false should be avoid. It set complete as a non-cache if added false in layout

Answer (score 0):

Magento used `cacheable="false"` in OOTB layout.

If page is independent then recommend to use `cacheable="false"`. Also avoid to add `cacheable="false"` in `default.xml` layout.