# Exclude caching cusotm module by Magento 2 built in Full page cache(FPC problem)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cache

I am having a strange issue regarding **built-in FPC** in magento2.

I have a custom module, in its **index controller**, it just renders a `phtml` file. This phtml file shows some information retrieving it from a custom table. This is just a simple thing that I have done here.

The problem is when I disable **FPC** in magento 2 the contents are displayed correctly, but when I enable the FPC than it renders the blank page .

See below two screeshot for the scenario analysis.
[image: Blank data when cache is enabled]

[image: Data when FPC is disabled]

Ok so what I have tried till now.

I read somewhere that including below code on block construct function excludes the block from FPC.

```
public function __construct(){
$this->_isScopePrivate = true;
}
```

But it didn't worked.

**What i want?**

I want to exclude my module from FPC.

Can anyone help me or enlight with some insights?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to disable your module from FPC, you can it from layout xml file but there is disable full page disable from FPC. it is not correct way.

Comment: sorry i don't understand what are you suggesting here. How can i do it from layout xml. Can you show some codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable block to cache by layout xml code.

See below example code for disable block from cache.

```
<block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="sample:module::sampletemplate.phtml" name="sampleblock" cacheable="false" />
```

**cacheable="false"** is use for that. you can disable like this.

Comment: This doesn't uncache the whole module Url's but this option works for me so i am accepting it.Thanks. By the way if i have a block called inside a static block, this trick is not working, do you have anything else for that case in mind?

Comment: add your code which you have try it in static block.

Comment: yes i added the cacheable="false" on block inside the static block but it is not working.

Comment: this solution worked for me  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103256/how-to-disable-the-cache-for-the-block-in-magento-2/148393#148393

Comment: cacheable="false" disables caching for the whole page!
This is NOT a proper solution, but a HUGE performance degradation recipe.
Please read https://inviqa.com/blog/how-full-page-cache-works-magento-2

Answer (score 2):

From

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-over.html

cacheable="false" will create **uncacheable page**, not just block.

For private content you should be using approach described in here:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html
- this page also says that using _isScopePrivate is deprecated.

You can check my answer also here why not to use *cacheable="false"* a bit more in details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/163875/4899