# I got the error 'Unable to serialize value' after upgrading the magento version to the 2.2.1

Tags: error, full-page-cache, magento-2.2.1, category-listing

I have upgraded **website 2.2.1** and facing **Unable to serialize value** error in particular product categories.

When I disabled the page cache (FPC) from the admin cache management then it works fine but when I enabled the page cache then I got the error.

But I need to enable page cache for optimization. Can you guys please help me!!!!

> {"0":"Unable to serialize value.","1":"#0 /home/infiniar/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/PageCache/
>       Kernel.php(153): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->serialize(Array)\n#1 /home/infiniar/public_html/vendor/
>       magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(96): Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Kernel->process
>       (Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#2 /home/infiniar/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/
>       Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->afterRenderResult(Object(
>       Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(
>       Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#3 /home/infiniar/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/
>       Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->
>       Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#4 /home/infiniar/
>       public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26): 
>       Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)\n#5 /home/infiniar/
>       public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(
>       Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#6 /home/infiniar/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App\
>       /Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#7 /home/infiniar/public_html/index.php(39): 
>       Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))\n#8 {main}","url":"/products/
>       computer-cases.html","script_name":"/index.php"}

Comment: Please review this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146154/exclude-caching-cusotm-module-by-magento-2-built-in-full-page-cachefpc-problem

Answer (score 1):

From magento 2.2, Magento  replaces usages of **unserialize** with `json_decode`.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes.html

If you using magento ***default cache system   and your system  is properly upgrade to  2.2*** then if you  will flush your cache storage **`database/Redis/memcache`** ,your issue will be resolve.

Either you have using ***any extensions*** which using ***serialize/Unserialize*** then you  need data upgrade to new json format/

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ext-best-practices/tutorials/serialized-to-json-data-upgrade.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/framework/serializer.html

Comment: i have searched memcache but it is not in my database can you tell me in which table the memcache is?

Comment: Can u please share ur `app/etc/env.php`,i will tell you the storage

Comment: Thanks for your reply, today i found issue in my list.phtml file with substring function so i have solved

Comment: excellent... good :)can u please post at here as an answer