# Magento 2 how to make block to non cacheble

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

I added code in `app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`  to hide price in homepage but due to cache, price block  hiding in product detail page as well. Here is my code,

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */
$objectInstance = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectInstance->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
$Actionname = $request->getFullActionName();


$productId = $block->getSaleableItem()->getId();

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$catalogSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Session');

$catalogSession->setFinalPrice();
$catalogSession->setActualPrice();
?>
<?php if($Actionname!="cms_index_index"):?>
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="discount-price">
        <?php
            $catalogSession->setFinalPrice($finalPriceModel->getValue());
            $catalogSession->setActualPrice($priceModel->getValue());
            $_savePercent = 100 - round((floatval($finalPriceModel->getValue()) / floatval($priceModel->getValue())) * 100);
           if($Actionname=="catalog_product_view"): echo "Discount: ".$finalPriceModel->getAmount(). " (".$_savePercent."%)";endif;?>

    </span>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl(); ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmountMinimal(); ?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmountMinimal(); ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When I checked for PriceBox block it was inside `<item>` tag, can any one help how to write for this particular block.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" cacheable="false" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">


<item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>

                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
```

Comment: You can use cacheable="false" in your layout file

Comment: I have tried by placing in layouts.xml, still the same issue. Can we invalidate cache by overriding `FinalPriceBox.php` file.  @Rakesh

Comment: This  solution worked for me http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103256/how-to-disable-the-cache-for-the-block-in-magento-2/148393#148393

Answer (score 1):

You can disable block to cache by layout xml code.

See below example code for disable block from cache.

```
<block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="sample:module::sampletemplate.phtml" name="sampleblock" cacheable="false" />
```

**cacheable="false"** is use for that. you can disable like this.

Answer (score 1):

Pass **cacheable="false"**  in your layout.xml file to disable the cache for block.

Try below code :

```
<block class="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Test" template="Vendor_modulename::test.phtml" name="testblock" cacheable="false" />
```

Comment: How can I write for  `FinalPriceBox` block.

Answer (score 0):

By using `cacheable="false"`, this will make your entire page non-cacheable. Alternatively you can use Ajax.

Comment: How can we make non-cacheable for particular block.

Comment: You need to use Ajax for same.