# Magento 2 Disable Cache for Dynamic Navigation Item

Tags: magento2, cache

I made an extension that adds an item to the header navigation if you are within a certain user group.   However, because of caching, it wont always show after logging in and wont always go away if you log out.

Is there a way around this?   I could disable caching for the block I think but it would cause the page itself to not cache and being that its on every page that would slow down the site dramatically.

Comment: Why do you think it would cause the whole page not to cache?

Comment: Read in a comment here  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103256/how-to-disable-the-cache-for-the-block-in-magento-2

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. +1 on the question; I'm curious too...

Comment: Please, read [this article (dev docs)](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html)

Answer (score 2):

(1) One option could be to create new controller what would return menu item(s) on POST ajax-call and store the result to browser's localStorage.

Call is made only then when there isn't any result yet in localStorage.

(2) Other option is to try builtin private content approach:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html

In following link has been mentioned that you need to use `CustomerData` sections for that:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155723/4899