# Public\private content

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, block-cache

Refering to this piece of docs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html, is it possible to put some private content into page which is public and it will not make whole page not cacheable? In other words to reload only PART of page dynamically, not invalidating a cache? Is it the way from docs above?

Comment: Can use `cacheable="false"` in ur `xml` file

Comment: but it will make whole page not cacheable

Comment: Correct. Using `cacheable=false` is absolutely not the right solution. Do not use this, because it will disable Full Page Caching for the entire page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generate customer private data you need to use `CustomerData` sections and rendering private html content on client side using data, provided by `CustomerData` sections or loaded via AJAX, as described in the DevDocs.

There are some modules, which successfully use this mechanism:

- Wishlist
- Product Compare
- Sales
- Checkout
- Review

Comment: I know - I heav read it - my question is - if inserting some private content into public-content page makes it entire not cacheable

Comment: magento application doesn't know which content is private and which is public. If you have placed any private content on the cacheable page, then content will be cached. You need to take care of this self (by using customer data).