# Magento 2.3 cache menu on homepage

Tags: magento2.3, cache, menu

I met this case sometimes on Homepage.
The menu was cached when I return Homepage from another category page.

Does anybody here have idea and solution for that?

[image: 3]

Thanks

Comment: have you tried in private window?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is full page cache issue, You can try with your menu block add this content in menu add **cacheable="false"** like this :

`<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="themes_header" template="html/header.phtml" cacheable="false" before="-">`

Comment: doing this to solve your problem but **cacheable="false"** is a big mistake, **it will make entire page not to cache**, if you mistakenly added in **default handler then entire website will not cache**. try to avoid use this.

Comment: we just put only in menu.nav block not for whole site or any .phtml

Comment: i guess you not seen how magento playing with layout xml files, magento merging all xml together so **it surely impact respective pages where this menu.nav is coming**, hope it help you to understand please don't mind, i just help you to not get in trouble.

Comment: for detail reference follow this link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103319/52244

Comment: Thank both of you. So I'm still waiting for the best solution.

Comment: Hi, I found this issue appear in list of Magento bugs.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22407