# Magento 2 - Current url not work well in copyright section

Tags: magento2, php, url, copyright

I need to get the current url in the copyright.phtml section.

This is my code:

```
echo $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);
```

After clearing the cache it seems to work but when I change the page the link is always the same and doesn't change.

This problem only happens to me in the copyright.phtml section. Why?

Comment: Because it's coming from the cache. You can disable the cache but it will disable Full Page Caching for the whole page. And Footer is always there so it will slow your site. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103319

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to echo the current URL you can do this

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<small class="copyright">
    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCopyright()) ?></span>
    <p class="currentURL"></p>
</small>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery","domReady!"], function ($) {

            var currentURL = window.location.href;
            $('.currentURL').text(currentURL);

    });
</script>
```