# Getting Customer Session null from custom module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, customer-session

I tried to get the `customer session` in my custom module, but it is getting **null** always when using `<update handle="customer_update"/>` in the layout file.

If I comment `<update handle="customer_update"/>` the customer session is getting.

And My code is below.

**Block** file

```
<?php

namespace Learning\CustomerAccLink\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as Session;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class CustomerLink extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * Session object.
     *
     * @var Session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     *
     * Object initialization.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $session
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $session,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->customerSession = $session;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get Customer Group ID
     *
     * @return int
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getCustomerGPID(): int
    {
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        /*try {

        }catch (LocalizedException|NoSuchEntityException $ex){
            return 0;
        }*/
    }

}
```

**Controller** file

```
  <?php

namespace Learning\CustomerAccLink\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;


    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //echo "Hello";
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }

}
```

**routes.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="learning" frontName="learning">
            <module name="Learning_CustomerAccLink" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**module.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_CustomerAccLink" >
    </module>
</config>
```

**customer_account.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
      label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
        <referenceContainer name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current"
                   name="customer-account-navigation-custom-link" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">learning</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**learning_index_index.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <!-- <update handle="customer_account"/>-->
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Learning\CustomerAccLink\Block\CustomerLink" name="custom_customer_link" template="customerLink.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="root">
            <action method="setHeaderTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Customer Link | Learning</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**customerLink.xml** file

```
<?php

/** @var $block Learning\CustomerAccLink\Block\CustomerLink */

?>


<?php  echo $block->getCustomerGPID(); ?>
```

**registration.php** file

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Learning_CustomerAccLink',
    __DIR__
);
```

Was there I missed any?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add cacheable="false" in your xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Customer" name="customer.session.data" template="Vendor_Modulename::customertab.phtml" cacheable="false" />
 </referenceContainer>
```

and get customer data :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 */
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    ) 
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCustomerId(){
    $customer = $this->_customerSession->create();
    var_dump($customer->getCustomer()->getId());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Without `cacheable="false"` can't get? Any reason?

Comment: Another way to get customer id with out cachable = "false" is httpContext

Comment: it is depend on which page.

Comment: Ok, All other modules it is working. When using `<update handle="customer_account"/>` it is not working.

Comment: so remove <update handle="customer_account"/> and use httpContext ,

Comment: https://mageclues.com/blog/how-to-get-logged-in-customer-data-using-httpcontext-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you please tell me which solution is working for you ?

Comment: Your solution `cacheable="false"` is working.

Comment: @Bojjaiah A single cacheable="false" will disable Full Page Caching for the whole page, making the pages sourcing from that layout file extremely slow!

Comment: @Msquare that is not a problem. Customer account area should *never* be in full page cache.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer @Craig. So data is not coming from the cache so why we did not get updated customer IDs or any data in the customer account area while we add our custom layout without cacheable="false"?

Answer (score 0):

> If you cannot get customer id at your block class when your page hits full page cache. You have to pass the **customer id** as an ***HTTP context*** variable.
> Create a **plugin**  class on `Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction`.

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction">
        <plugin name="get_customr_id_full_page"  disabled="false" sortOrder="20" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction"/>
    </type>

    </type>
</config>
```

**On plugin pass current customer id as http context variable:**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Plugin/Framework/App/Action**

**AbstractAction.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Framework\App\Action;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class AbstractAction
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    private $httpContext;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function aroundDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {

        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomerId();
        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            'current_cust_id',
            $customerId,
            0
        );

        return $proceed($request);
    }
}
```

After that Inject, `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` on your block class and get this customer id value by  `$this->httpContext->getValue('current_cust_id')`

***Note: A single cacheable="false" will disable Full Page Caching for the whole page, making the pages sourcing from that layout file extremely slow!***
[**Click here for more**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/163875/82670)