# Latest data doesn't show at front end after addding data in my custom module

Tags: product, frontend, cache, data, page-content

Latest data does not show at front-end after submitting form in my custom module.
when I clear cache then latest data show at front end.

**Help me! how to fix that problem.**

when I disable cache my module work correctly but I want to displaying latest data at front side without disable cache.

Comment: Please check this :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/306517/85907

Answer (score 1):

You can flush cache programmatically in your controller, So don't need to clear cache manually and don't need to disable cache for particular block.
Please check the below code for  cache clear

1.Add below lines after namespace

```
use Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Version;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool;
```

2.Define variables

```
protected $cacheTypeList;

protected $cacheFrontendPool;
```

3. Add params to construct method

```
/**
 * Cache clear
 *
 * @param TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
 * @param Pool $cacheFrontendPool
 */
public function __construct(
    TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList, 
    Pool $cacheFrontendPool
) {
    $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    $this->cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
}
```

4. The Last step for clearing the cache in your execute method

```
    $_types = [
        'config',
        'block_html',
        'full_page',
        'config_webservice'
    ];
 
    foreach ($_types as $type) {
        $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
    }
    foreach ($this->cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
        $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
    }
```

You can check [here](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/clear-cache-programmically-magento-2.html)

Sometimes I also faced this type of issue, at this time I use this way.

I hope it's an alternative way without disabling the cache and manually clearing the cache, Your submitted form data will show in the frontend.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for giving solution. My custom module work perfectly by this solution. But, I think it is a bad practice because performance(increase loading time of page) of module will be lose by clear cache programmatically.I want to find solution by js.

Comment: you are right @MuhammadZahoor, This is a bad practice by clearing cache, it down the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add cacheable false for the particular PHTML file like below.

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Customer\Recent" name="customer_account_dashboard_info1" template="Magento_Review::customer/recent1.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

Comment: I know, by this solution it work correctly but I want to finding alternating solution because I doesn't want to define cache false for a block.
Kindly give alternative solution for this.