# Magento 2: When to use cachable=false in Layout file

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, cache

In Layout XML file, if we don't want to cache a block we use `cachable=false`. By default, it's going to cache.

**When to use `cachable=false` & how it effects to website performance?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting a block element `cacheable` attribute to false can serve several purposes!

- Used for development purposes if you don't want the block to be cached when you develop the block code
- Make the element of the page dynamic

For example, the **captcha block `\Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha` is not cached in Magento 2**. It makes sense as it is a dynamic block.

### Beware

Something you've got to keep in mind, is that **if the `cacheable` attribute is set to false on a block, it will make the entire page not cacheable which is not ideal in terms of performance.**

Obviously, **the more uncacheable blocks you have the worse the performance will be.**

Comment: So to make a page cacheable each block on the page should be set to cacheable?

Comment: @amitshree http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93473/2380