# How can I disable cache for particular section or block in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, blocks, cache, full-page-cache

I am making a online payment method, which is taking previous cart details if Full page cache is enabled. **How can we make it non cache-able?** I want to make my HTML content non - cache-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `cacheable="false"` for your perticular section or block.

ex.

```
<block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha" name="captcha" cacheable="false"></block>
```

You can get more info from core modules of magento.

Comment: Doing this will render the entire page un-cached in FPC. See here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html

Comment: How to disable cache in checkout page?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer:

**Using `cacheable="false"` will make the entire page that contains this block not cacheable.** So you don't disable cache for one block. You can find more references below:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103319/2380
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93473/2380

Answer (score 0):

You have to add with your block in layout file

```
cacheable="false"
```

For Exanple

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Registration" name="checkout.registration" template="registration.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is never recommended.
This is because the entire page cache cannot be handled with this approach.