# Magento2: Home page caching issue

Tags: magento2, javascript, full-page-cache, caching

I have added java-script in the footer like below and I am passing the customer email dynamically, but the same email id is displaying for all the customers because the page is caching.

[image]

Please help me to fix this cache issue.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, avoiding using Object Manager directly in our template. This is not good for best practice. Should create a new block and try to apply the solutions below:

### Solutions for Caching issue

#### <del>Using `after.body.start` or `before_body_end`</del>

[Seem that these blocks are cached]
<del>These blocks are not cached</del>. So, we can add your custom block to these containers. For example:

*Company/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class='Company\Module\Block\Module' name="js.tracking" as="js.tracking" template="Company_Module::tracking.phtml"/>
     </referenceContainer>
     <!--<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">-->
        <!--<block class='Company\Module\Block\Module' name="js.tracking" as="js.tracking" template="Company_Module::tracking.phtml"/>-->
    <!--</referenceContainer>-->
   </body>
</page>
```

Add tracking js to your custom template: `Company/Module/view/frontend/templates/tracking.phtml`

Should take a look at Google Analytics module: `vendor/magento/module-google-analytics`.

#### Disable caching of the block

Read more here: [How do disable caching of custom block on product view page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93455/how-do-disable-caching-of-custom-block-on-product-view-page). However, currently, this way should not try because make the pages contain [this block uncacheable.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1817)

#### Ajax

I like this way, we should try with Ajax.

--Suggests other solutions:

#### Local storage

Magento 2 stores cart info on local storage, we can add more customer info to cart info. And then, use it in our custom script.

#### Global Js variable

Go to `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml`, we can see that Magento uses some global variables to store checkout info(including customer data).

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `cacheable="false"` prevents the whole page from being cached, not enough people know about this.