# Disable cache for custom block file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, products, product-collection, random

I want to show random product collection on custom template. But It is showing random product only after clear cache otherwise it shows same products.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks can be set as non-cacheable by setting the `cacheable` attribute `false` in layout XML files. For example

`<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="false" />`

Pages containing such blocks are not cached.

Also, check [How do disable caching of custom block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93455/how-do-disable-caching-of-custom-block-on-product-view-page)

Comment: I am not calling file this way.  calling template file in block file.  I have a block function and fetching collection on that with random on select query..

Comment: add that code in your question.