# Why is DI working in controller but not in Blocks?

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom-block, checkoutsession

I was trying my hand on Magento 2. I am able to get the checkout session data inside a controller by injecting `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,` in controllers construct method.

But when I try to do the same in a Block class, Im unable to get any data from check out session.

```
<?php
namespace Company\Hello\Block;

class Main extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Company\Hello\Model\Test $model,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->_model   =   $model;
        $this->_request =   $request;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        // print_r($this->_request->getParams());
        // exit;
        // $this->_model->getDbData();
        $this->setCntnt(__('Hello World 2.0'));
    }
    public function getAddedProduct()
    {
        foreach ($this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            echo $item->getName();
        }
        exit('block class');
    }
}
```

Whereas I am able to access the object (`$this->_checkoutSession`) but can't get any value.

> I call the method `getAddedProduct()` in the template file

can someone clarify this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to inject Checkout session and need to create()**

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Checkout\Model\SessionFactory $session
    ) {
        $this->session= $session;
       parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

then use getAllVisibleItems

```
 $checkout = $this->session->create()->getQuote();
    foreach ($checkout->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {  
      echo $item->getName();
    }
```

if work then plz accept the answere.

Comment: People! please add a comment why you downvoted this answer. This solution is working for me, but need to know why this was not recommended. Expert advise welcome.

Comment: This is working for me as well +1

Answer (score 0):

In your construct method, add **`$this->_isScopePrivate = true;`**. Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Onepage/Link.php`

You can try `cacheable="false"` in your layout xml also.

Read more: [How do disable caching of custom block on product view page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93455/how-do-disable-caching-of-custom-block-on-product-view-page)

Comment: setting _isScopePrivate didn't help, can you pls explain why "$this->_isScopePrivate = true;" should be set?

Comment: @Shathish you should read more here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93473/33057

Comment: @Shathish you also try with `cacheable="false"` in your layout xml. You should try again and let me know.