# Magento 2 - Recently viewed product not working with FPC

Tags: magento2, event-observer, full-page-cache, recently-viewed

Magento default functionality of recently viewed product uses the following event to save viewed history

```
catalog_controller_product_view
```

And it stores in following tables

```
report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily
report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly
report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly
report_viewed_product_index /*(Probably this one too)*/
```

It worked perfectly until you enable FPC the event `catalog_controller_product_view` would not work with FPC.

I know the event that will work with FPC. it is `controller_front_send_response_before` but the problem is, you can not get current product from `$this->_registry->registry('current_product');` this will also stopped working with FPC.

My question is, how can we resolve this issue, how can we store recently viewed information in above tables while FPC is enabled.

Comment: This should help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181827/recently-viewed-not-showing-up-when-full-page-cache-is-enable