# How can disable the cache for some block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, geoip

Please check Below code. 
I have try to get customer country code on footer.phtml. I have used GeoIP plugin to get. And added this code to block. Anyone let me know that How can I get this code out of a cache.

Issue: currently all visitor get the same county due to load this block from the cache.

```
namespace Rokanthemes\Themeoption\Block;
    class Themeoption extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
    {
        public $geoIpService;

        public function __construct(
            \MagePal\GeoIp\Service\GeoIpService $geoIpService,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->geoIpService = $geoIpService;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);

        }
        public function ipCountry()
        {
            return $this->geoIpService->getCountry();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->addData(
        [
            'cache_lifetime' => false,
            'cache_tags' => ['Rokanthemes_Themeoption', \Magento\Store\Model\Group::CACHE_TAG],
        ]
    );
}
```

**OR**

Add below function in your block file

```
public function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return false;
}
```

**OR**

Set cacheable attribute false in your module layout XML file. For your block

```
<block class="Rokanthemes\Themeoption\Block\Themeoption" name="themeoption" cacheable="false" />
```

Comment: Not work. I have tried all three methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting `cacheable` attribute `false` in layout XML files.

```
<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="false" />
```

You can also check this link
[How do disable caching of custom block on product view page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93455/how-do-disable-caching-of-custom-block-on-product-view-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent a block or phtml from cache use `cacheable="false"` in your layout xml file.

```
<block cacheable="false" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml" />
```