# Magento 2 - Disable Page cache for login/register page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, full-page-cache, registration, login-register

I am facing issue with **FPC**, **login and register** pages, are adding in **Page Cache**, I need to **disable** it.

I have idea that if we add **`cacheable="false"`** in any one of block that is used in **login/register** page then whole page would be excluded from Page Cache.

Is it a good way of disabling cache on specific page or is there any other way around to do this?

Comment: please refer this [How do disable caching of custom block on product view page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93455/how-do-disable-caching-of-custom-block-on-product-view-page/#answer-93473)

Comment: Thanks for shareing Abhishek, but I don't want to disable blocks, that could be done using hole punching or placeholder. I want do disable whole login and register page, not just block

Comment: adding a cacheable="false" into any block will automatically makes the entire page not to be cached so you can add that if you want it for the entire page & if you want it for a specific block you can go with the above link thanks!

Comment: Thanks Abhishek :) what `cacheable="false"` will do, already described in my question. My main question is, is it a good way to disable cache on page like this, or is there any other Magento way of disable cache for specific page.

Comment: cacheable="false" is the way to do it. best practice

Comment: Thanks @PhilippSander :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research and comments of Phillipp Sander, I have concluded that `cacheable="false"` is to good approach to make any **page exclude from full page cache**.

**For login page**, I have updated `customer_account_login.xml` file in my theme and updated this line:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml" cacheable="false">
```

**For signup page**, I have updated `customer_account_create.xml` file in my theme and updated this line:

```
<block class="Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Block\Form" template="Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes::form/userattributes.phtml" name="customer_form_user_attributes" cacheable="false">
```

This worked for me. Hope it will helpful for others too :)