# Get Customer ID from Session Model

Tags: magento2

I've a helper and in the __construct() something like:

```
public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;

    }
```

he problem is when I can the $_customerSession object data it's empty, even though I've logged in.

It seems the session is instantiated at a later point in the process, because if I call the customer\Session object in a page Model or block it works fine. In fact, the whole store works as expected. I can see the logged in welcome message at the top right bar, add products to cart, login.

Thecode above is dispatched in the event

```
catalog_product_get_final_price
```

How do I make sure the session is loaded or how do I know when it's loaded?

Comment: have  add `use \Magento\Customer\Model\Session` on that class

Comment: @AmitBera, I've added it, But I don't see why this could have been be the issue. I can access the class, but the problem is that it's not populated with data.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @LM_Fielding No.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the problem too. The problem occurs when cache is enabled.

Please see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2010

[Block with Cachable=false not rendered on product view page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86674/block-with-cachable-false-not-rendered-on-product-view-page/90130#90130)

Comment: How did you get around it? I'm considering adding a child block in my layout so I can access in my block class?