# How did these theme developers manage to not use cache on their MegaMenu?

Tags: magento2, cache

These theme developers are not caching this block and creating performance issues for hundreds if not thousands of Magento 2 sites.

The megamenu implementation is not being cached, why is this?

**topmenu.phtml**

```
    <?php
        $_helper = $this->helper('Clumsywave\Mega\Helper\Data');
        $_config = $_helper->getConfig('cw_mega');
        $columnsLimit = 0;
        $header_type = $_helper->getConfig('clumsy_settings/header/header_type');

        if($_config['general']['enable']) {
    ?>
<?php $_menu = $block->getMegamenuHtml(); ?>

<nav class="navigation sw-megamenu <?php if($header_type == 8 || $header_type == 10): ?>side-megamenu<?php endif; ?>" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <?php echo $_menu; ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Clumsywave\Mega\Block\Topmenu.php**

```
class Topmenu extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_categoryHelper;
    protected $_categoryFlatConfig;
    protected $_topMenu;
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_helper;
    protected $_filterProvider;
    protected $_blockFactory;
    protected $_megamenuConfig;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Clumsywave\Mega\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topMenu,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory
    ) {

        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->_categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_topMenu = $topMenu;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCategoryHelper()
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper;
    }

    public function getCategoryModel($id)
    {
        $_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
        $_category->load($id);

        return $_category;
    }

    public function getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
    {
        return $this->_topMenu->getHtml($outermostClass, $childrenWrapClass, $limit);
    }

    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

    public function getChildCategories($category)
    {
        if ($this->_categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
            $subcategories = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
        } else {
            $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
        }

        return $subcategories;
    }

    public function getActiveChildCategories($category)
    {
        $children = [];
        if ($this->_categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
            $subcategories = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
        } else {
            $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
        }
        foreach($subcategories as $category) {
            if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
                continue;
            }
            $children[] = $category;
        }
        return $children;
    }

    public function getBlockContent($content = '') {
        if(!$this->_filterProvider)
            return $content;
        return $this->_filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->filter(trim($content));
    }

    public function getCustomBlockHtml($type='after') {
        $html = '';

        $block_ids = $this->_megamenuConfig['custom_links']['staticblock_'.$type];

        if (!$block_ids) return '';

        $block_ids = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $block_ids);
        $ids = explode(',', $block_ids);
        $store_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        foreach($ids as $block_id) {
            $block = $this->_blockFactory->create();
            $block->setStoreId($store_id)->load($block_id);

            if(!$block) continue;

            $block_content = $block->getContent();

            if(!$block_content) continue;

            $content = $this->_filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($store_id)->filter($block_content);
            if(substr($content, 0, 4) == '<ul>')
                $content = substr($content, 4);
            if(substr($content, strlen($content) - 5) == '</ul>')
                $content = substr($content, 0, -5);

            $html .= $content;
        }

        return $html;
    }
    public function getSubmenuItemsHtml($children, $level = 1, $max_level = 0, $column_width=12, $menu_type = 'fullwidth', $columns = null)
    {
        $html = '';

        if(!$max_level || ($max_level && $max_level == 0) || ($max_level && $max_level > 0 && $max_level-1 >= $level)) {
            $column_class = "";
            if($level == 1 && $columns && ($menu_type == 'fullwidth' || $menu_type == 'staticwidth')) {
                $column_class = "col-sm-".$column_width." ";
                $column_class .= "mega-columns columns".$columns;
            }
            $html = '<ul class="subchildmenu '.$column_class.'">';
            foreach($children as $child) {
                $cat_model = $this->getCategoryModel($child->getId());

                $sw_menu_hide_item = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_hide_item');

                if (!$sw_menu_hide_item) {
                    $sub_children = $this->getActiveChildCategories($child);

                    $sw_menu_cat_label = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_cat_label');
                    $sw_menu_icon_img = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_icon_img');
                    $sw_menu_font_icon = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_font_icon');

                    $item_class = 'level'.$level.' ';
                    if(count($sub_children) > 0)
                        $item_class .= 'parent ';
                    $html .= '<li class="ui-menu-item '.$item_class.'">';
                    if(count($sub_children) > 0) {
                        $html .= '<div class="open-children-toggle"></div>';
                    }
                    if($level == 1 && $sw_menu_icon_img) {
                        $html .= '<div class="menu-thumb-img"><a class="menu-thumb-link" href="'.$this->_categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($child).'"><img src="' . $this->_helper->getBaseUrl().'catalog/category/' . $sw_menu_icon_img . '" alt="'.$child->getName().'"/></a></div>';
                    }
                    $html .= '<a href="'.$this->_categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($child).'">';
                    if ($level > 1 && $sw_menu_icon_img)
                        $html .= '<img class="menu-thumb-icon" src="' . $this->_helper->getBaseUrl().'catalog/category/' . $sw_menu_icon_img . '" alt="'.$child->getName().'"/>';
                    elseif($sw_menu_font_icon)
                        $html .= '<em class="menu-thumb-icon '.$sw_menu_font_icon.'"></em>';
                    $html .= '<span>'.$child->getName();
                    if($sw_menu_cat_label)
                        $html .= '<span class="cat-label cat-label-'.$sw_menu_cat_label.'">'.$this->_megamenuConfig['cat_labels'][$sw_menu_cat_label].'</span>';
                    $html .= '</span></a>';
                    if(count($sub_children) > 0) {
                        $html .= $this->getSubmenuItemsHtml($sub_children, $level+1, $max_level, $column_width, $menu_type);
                    }
                    $html .= '</li>';
                }
            }
            $html .= '</ul>';
        }

        return $html;
    }

    public function getMegamenuHtml()
    {
        $html = '';

        $categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);

        $this->_megamenuConfig = $this->_helper->getConfig('sw_megamenu');

        $max_level = $this->_megamenuConfig['general']['max_level'];
        $html .= $this->getCustomBlockHtml('before');
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
                continue;
            }

            $cat_model = $this->getCategoryModel($category->getId());

            $sw_menu_hide_item = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_hide_item');

            if(!$sw_menu_hide_item) {
                $children = $this->getActiveChildCategories($category);
                $sw_menu_cat_label = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_cat_label');
                $sw_menu_icon_img = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_icon_img');
                $sw_menu_font_icon = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_font_icon');
                $sw_menu_cat_columns = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_cat_columns');
                $sw_menu_float_type = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_float_type');

                if(!$sw_menu_cat_columns){
                    $sw_menu_cat_columns = 4;
                }

                $menu_type = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_type');
                if(!$menu_type)
                    $menu_type = $this->_megamenuConfig['general']['menu_type'];

                $custom_style = '';
                if($menu_type=="staticwidth")
                    $custom_style = ' style="width: 500px;"';

                $sw_menu_static_width = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_static_width');
                if($menu_type=="staticwidth" && $sw_menu_static_width)
                    $custom_style = ' style="width: '.$sw_menu_static_width.';"';

                $item_class = 'level0 ';
                $item_class .= $menu_type.' ';

                $menu_top_content = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_block_top_content');
                $menu_left_content = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_block_left_content');
                $menu_left_width = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_block_left_width');
                if(!$menu_left_content || !$menu_left_width)
                    $menu_left_width = 0;
                $menu_right_content = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_block_right_content');
                $menu_right_width = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_block_right_width');
                if(!$menu_right_content || !$menu_right_width)
                    $menu_right_width = 0;
                $menu_bottom_content = $cat_model->getData('sw_menu_block_bottom_content');
                if($sw_menu_float_type)
                    $sw_menu_float_type = 'fl-'.$sw_menu_float_type.' ';
                if(count($children) > 0 || (($menu_type=="fullwidth" || $menu_type=="staticwidth") && ($menu_top_content || $menu_left_content || $menu_right_content || $menu_bottom_content)))
                    $item_class .= 'parent ';
                $html .= '<li class="ui-menu-item '.$item_class.$sw_menu_float_type.'">';
                if(count($children) > 0) {
                    $html .= '<div class="open-children-toggle"></div>';
                }
                $html .= '<a href="'.$this->_categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category).'" class="level-top">';
                if ($sw_menu_icon_img)
                    $html .= '<img class="menu-thumb-icon" src="' . $this->_helper->getBaseUrl().'catalog/category/' . $sw_menu_icon_img . '" alt="'.$category->getName().'"/>';
                elseif($sw_menu_font_icon)
                    $html .= '<em class="menu-thumb-icon '.$sw_menu_font_icon.'"></em>';
                $html .= '<span>'.$category->getName().'</span>';
                if($sw_menu_cat_label)
                    $html .= '<span class="cat-label cat-label-'.$sw_menu_cat_label.'">'.$this->_megamenuConfig['cat_labels'][$sw_menu_cat_label].'</span>';
                $html .= '</a>';
                if(count($children) > 0 || (($menu_type=="fullwidth" || $menu_type=="staticwidth") && ($menu_top_content || $menu_left_content || $menu_right_content || $menu_bottom_content))) {
                    $html .= '<div class="level0 submenu"'.$custom_style.'>';
                    if(($menu_type=="fullwidth" || $menu_type=="staticwidth") && $menu_top_content) {
                        $html .= '<div class="menu-top-block">'.$this->getBlockContent($menu_top_content).'</div>';
                    }
                    if(count($children) > 0 || (($menu_type=="fullwidth" || $menu_type=="staticwidth") && ($menu_left_content || $menu_right_content))) {
                        $html .= '<div class="row">';
                        if(($menu_type=="fullwidth" || $menu_type=="staticwidth") && $menu_left_content && $menu_left_width > 0) {
                            $html .= '<div class="menu-left-block col-sm-'.$menu_left_width.'">'.$this->getBlockContent($menu_left_content).'</div>';
                        }
                        $html .= $this->getSubmenuItemsHtml($children, 1, $max_level, 12-$menu_left_width-$menu_right_width, $menu_type, $sw_menu_cat_columns);
                        if(($menu_type=="fullwidth" || $menu_type=="staticwidth") && $menu_right_content && $menu_right_width > 0) {
                            $html .= '<div class="menu-right-block col-sm-'.$menu_right_width.'">'.$this->getBlockContent($menu_right_content).'</div>';
                        }
                        $html .= '</div>';
                    }
                    if(($menu_type=="fullwidth" || $menu_type=="staticwidth") && $menu_bottom_content) {
                        $html .= '<div class="menu-bottom-block">'.$this->getBlockContent($menu_bottom_content).'</div>';
                    }
                    $html .= '</div>';
                }
                $html .= '</li>';
            }
        }
        $html .= $this->getCustomBlockHtml('after');

        return $html;
    }
}
```

**view/layout/default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Clumsywave\Mega\Block\Topmenu" name="sw.topnav" template="Clumsywave_Mega::topmenu.phtml" cacheable="true" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Clumsywave\Theme\Block\Template" name="category_list_on_left" template="Clumsywave_Mega::onepagecategory/category_list.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: By default blocks are initiated as `cacheable="true"`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Amit. Yes I though that was the case. But why would it then call `getMegamenuHtml()` on every request?

Comment: If all cache are enabled and blocks are initiated without `cacheable="false"`, Then getMegamenuHtml() will not be called. It will be called for first request of any page. If it is called every time then there may be some other block defined in your theme or module as `cacheable="false"`. The cacheable false of single block basically stops the caching of whole page.

Comment: Wouldn't it only not cache that block? Why would it stop cache of all other pages?

Comment: Do you think the `ttl` element is affecting it? `            {{block class="Clumsywave\Mega\Block\Topmenu" name="sw.sidenav" template="Smartwave_Megamenu::sidemenu.phtml" cacheable="true" ttl="86400"}}`

Comment: For any request, whenever there is any block defined as cacheable="false". The whole page cache is disabled. You can also refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93455/how-do-disable-caching-of-custom-block-on-product-view-page

Comment: Hmm, I'm talking about `block cache` in this instance. Not `page cache`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hmm, I'm talking about block cache in this instance. Not page cache.

I think that's where the confusion comes from. The comments in your question are right. The "problem" is that **Magento 2 considers a page to be "non cacheable" if  its layout contains blocks with `cacheable="false"` . If it does not, then the page is considered cacheable.**

That's pretty much what Amit was trying to explain in the comments:

> If all cache are enabled and blocks are initiated without
>   `cacheable="false"`, Then `getMegamenuHtml()` will not be called. It will
>   be called for first request of any page. If it is called every time
>   then there may be some other block defined in your theme or module as
>   `cacheable="false"`. The cacheable false of single block basically stops
>   the caching of whole page.

So in your case, one block of that layout must be non cacheable, thus the entire page is non cacheable.

You can learn more about it here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90130/2380

Comment: Yes, but this is bad. So you are saying there is no block level cache anymore. The html has been generated for that block. But it needs to be regenerated again just because it is a new page.

Comment: @StevieG in Magento 2, `cacheable="false"` means the entire page is not cacheable period.